# Extract USD amout at beginning of string using regex

Tags: regex

Need help to extract the usd amount at beginning of string.

Example

String : `$50,000.00 NAMED INSURED FOR $100K/$300K LIMITS` 
Output : `50,000`

This is what I tried `\$\d.*?000\.00` but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\$?([\d,\.]+)\b
```

Or something of the sort. Broken down:

```
^            # anchor to start of line
\$?          # look for dollar sign (but optional)
(            # begin capture group
  [\d,\.]+   # match 1 or more of the following: `0-9`, `,` or `.`
)            # end capture group
\b           # word boundary
```

Example of the above can be found here: http://regexr.com?372t4

*note:* if you're looking to convert this in to a double/float value in a language, you're going to need a parser that ignores commas or do some simple string manipulation to remove them.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` when specified within a character class.

Comment: @devnull: indeed, but like to (esp on SO) for beginners so when they use it elsewhere they don't wonder why it works in some instances and not in others. ;-)

Comment: And you can lose the wrapping slashes too - they have nothing to do with regex

Comment: @Santosh: No problem, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
\$(\S+)
```

which will give you `50,000.00` -- the exact amount.

Find the `$` sign and then match all non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^\$(\d{1,3}(?=,\d{3})*.\d{2})
```